# Get column index from label in a data frame

Tags: r

Say we have the following data frame:

```
> df
  A B C
1 1 2 3
2 4 5 6
3 7 8 9
```

We can select column 'B' from its index:

```
> df[,2]
[1] 2 5 8
```

Is there a way to get the index (2) from the column label ('B')?

Comment: See @matthewdowle's answer here for the best solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9277935/636656

Answer (score 137, accepted):

you can get the index via `grep` and `colnames`:

```
grep("B", colnames(df))
[1] 2
```

or use

```
grep("^B$", colnames(df))
[1] 2
```

to only get the columns called "B" without those who contain a B e.g. "ABC".

Comment: Your original example's advantages could be demonstrated in code if you showed its use in something like df[ , grep("^B", colnames(df)) ], i.e, returning the dataframe columns starting with "B". Feel free to use in a further edit if you agree.

Comment: Or even df[ , grep("^[BC]", colnames(df)) ], i.e., the columns that start with either B or C.

Comment: @Dwin: As @aix already said, the asker wants the *index*. But I also usually use `grep` the way you describe it.

Comment: @Henrik. Thank you so much. This must be the single most useful command to work with dplyr and variables!

Answer (score 109):

The following will do it:

```
which(colnames(df)=="B")
```

Comment: The problem with `grep` is also the advantage, namely that it uses regular expressions (so you can search for any pattern in your colnames). To just get the colnames "B" use `"^B$"` as the pattern in grep. ^ is the metacharacter for the beginning and $ for the end of a string.

Comment: You don't even need `which`. You can directly use `df[names(df)=="B"]`

Comment: @nico The question is to get the *index* of the column.

Comment: "Which" worked for me in every case. I couldn't get a column with the name "fBodyAcc-meanFreq()-Z" using grep.

Comment: @Kabamaru: Grep will work as long as you escape the metacharacters.  For the example you gave, this will work: `grep("^fBodyAcc-meanFreq\\()-Z$",colnames(df))` or also `grep("^fBodyAcc-meanFreq\\(\\)-Z$",colnames(df))`.

Comment: @NPE Can you guide me how can I pass the name of a column to a variable. For example with following line of code I want to pass colname of column 4 to variable a:  `a <- colnames(df[,4])` but it is not working.

Answer (score 9):

I wanted to see all the indices for the colnames because I needed to do a complicated [column rearrangement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620885/how-does-one-reorder-columns-in-a-data-frame), so I printed the colnames as a dataframe.  The rownames are the indices.

```
as.data.frame(colnames(df))

1 A
2 B
3 C
```

Comment: A more concise way to do this is `cbind(names(df))`.

Comment: @lillemets if brevity is your goal, `t(t(names(df)))` saves you 2 characters ;)

Answer (score 7):

Following on from *chimeric's* answer above:

To get **ALL the column indices** in the **df**, so i used:

```
which(!names(df)%in%c())
```

or store in a list:

```
indexLst<-which(!names(df)%in%c())
```

Comment: i think this is the best answer because it can be generalized

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be an efficient way to list vars with column number:

```
cbind(names(df))
```

Output:

```
     [,1]
[1,] "A" 
[2,] "B" 
[3,] "C"
```

Sometimes I like to copy variables with position into my code so I use this function:

```
varnums<- function(x) {w=as.data.frame(c(1:length(colnames(x))),
          paste0('# ',colnames(x)))
names(w)= c("# Var/Pos")
w}
varnums(df)
```

Output:

```
# Var/Pos
# A         1
# B         2
# C         3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
match("B", names(df))
```

Can work also if you have a vector of names.

Answer (score 1):

To generalize @NPE's answer slightly:

```r
which(colnames(dat) %in% var)
```

where var is of the form

```r
c("colname1","colname2",...,"colnamen")
```

returns the indices of whichever column names one needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `t` function:

```
t(colnames(df))

     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]  
[1,] "var1" "var2" "var3" "var4" "var5" "var6"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that will generalize Henrik's answer.

```
df=data.frame(A=rnorm(100), B=rnorm(100), C=rnorm(100))
numeric_columns<-c('A', 'B', 'C')
numeric_index<-sapply(1:length(numeric_columns), function(i)
grep(numeric_columns[i], colnames(df)))
```

Comment: That `sapply` is a long way to write `match(numeric_columns, names(df))` --- unless you really need the regex power rather than exact string matching.

Comment: thanks @GregorThomas...not super familar with match.  In this case it is quite a bit shorter, but I like the sapply because it's a little more explicit what is going on...to each their own i guess (havem't benchmarked any performance differences)

Answer (score 0):

#I wanted the column index instead of the column name. This line of code worked for me:

```r
which (data.frame (colnames (datE)) == colnames (datE[c(1:15)]), arr.ind = T)[,1]

#with datE being a regular dataframe with 15 columns (variables)

data.frame(colnames(datE))
#>    colnames.datE.
#> 1              Ce
#> 2              Eu
#> 3              La
#> 4              Pr
#> 5              Nd
#> 6              Sm
#> 7              Gd
#> 8              Tb
#> 9              Dy
#> 10             Ho
#> 11             Er
#> 12              Y
#> 13             Tm
#> 14             Yb
#> 15             Lu

which(data.frame(colnames(datE))==colnames(datE[c(1:15)]),arr.ind=T)[,1]
#> [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```