# How to reorder data.table columns (without copying)

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to reorder columns in my `data.table` `x`, given a character vector of column names, `neworder`:

```
library(data.table)
x <- data.table(a = 1:3, b = 3:1, c = runif(3))
neworder <- c("c", "b", "a")
```

Obviously I could do:

```
x[ , neworder, with = FALSE]
# or
x[ , ..neworder]
#            c b a
# 1: 0.8476623 3 1
# 2: 0.4787768 2 2
# 3: 0.3570803 1 3
```

but that would require copying the entire dataset again. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Use `setcolorder()`:

```
library(data.table)
x <- data.table(a = 1:3, b = 3:1, c = runif(3))
x
#      a b         c
# [1,] 1 3 0.2880365
# [2,] 2 2 0.7785115
# [3,] 3 1 0.3297416
setcolorder(x, c("c", "b", "a"))
x
#              c b a
# [1,] 0.2880365 3 1
# [2,] 0.7785115 2 2
# [3,] 0.3297416 1 3
```

From `?setcolorder`:

> In `data.table` parlance, all `set*` functions change their input by reference. That is, no copy is made at all, other than temporary working memory, which is as large as one column.

so should be pretty efficient. See `?setcolorder` for details.

Comment: Small clarification: `setcolorder` moves the column pointers around without using any working memory at all. That sentence about using working memory as large as one column is just about `setkey` really.

Comment: @MatthewDowle - thanks for the clarification. I sort of thought that may have been the case, but wasn't 100% sure.

Comment: can I do that for a subset of columns? For example when I just want to move to columns to the front?

Comment: `setcolorder(df, c("someCol",colnames(dt)[!(colnames(dt) %in% c("someCol"))]))`

Comment: @PeterPan See also [NEWS about the devel version 1.10.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md): "`setcolorder()` now accepts less than `ncol(DT)` columns to be moved to the front"

Comment: @Henrik Timely!  I was looking for a way to move the key column to the front, that will fit the bill nicely when it's released.

Comment: Is it possible to move a few columns (selected by name) to the back at all?

Answer (score 19):

One may find it easier to use the above solution, but instead sort by column number. For example:
        library(data.table)

```
    > x <- data.table(a = 1:3, b = 3:1, c = runif(3))
    > x
         a b         c
    [1,] 1 3 0.2880365
    [2,] 2 2 0.7785115
    [3,] 3 1 0.3297416
    > setcolorder(x, c(3,2,1))
    > x
         c         b a
    [1,] 0.2880365 3 1
    [2,] 0.7785115 2 2
    [3,] 0.3297416 1 3
```

Comment: It is generally discouraged to refer to columns by number, in data.table and elsewhere. The data.table faq makes the argument for this in the first item here: http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf