# Add new variable to specific position in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a DF where I want to add a new variable called "B" into the 2nd position.

```
  A C D
1 1 5 2
2 3 3 7
3 6 2 3
4 6 4 8
5 1 1 2
```

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: `DF$B <- newvariable` ?

Comment: the order of the variables would look like A C D B. The order I want to have is A B C D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add the columns you want and then reorder them:

```
dat$B <- 1:5
newdat <- dat[, c("A", "B", "C", "D")]
```

Another way:

```
newdat <- cbind(dat[1], B=1:5, dat[,2:3])
```

If you're concerned about overhead, perhaps a `data.table` solution? (With help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12232123/1465387)):

```
library(data.table)
dattable <- data.table(dat)
dattable[,B:=1:5]
setcolorder(dattable, c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
```

Comment: this would work but with an immense overhead if the dataframe has hundreds of variables

Comment: Yea exactly my data frame is huge and I want to do this. Also my data frame might change from time to time so I don't want to reference a specific numbered position

Comment: If you don't want a specific numbered position, how do you know where to put it?

Answer (score 1):

```
dat$B <- 1:5 
ind <- c(1:which(names(data) == "A"),ncol(data),(which(names(data) == "A")+1):ncol(data)-1)
data <- data[,ind]
```

Create the variable at the end of the data.frame and then using an indicator vector signaling how to reorder the columns. ind is just a vector of numbers

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have (and most of us do have) a data frame with more than only a few variables, so putting in every column name or number manually would be too much effort! However, your code should be adjusted as follows: `(ncol(data)-1)`. If you forget the extra brackets, column A gets a copy A.1.