# Changing columns positions in a data frame without total reassignment

Tags: r

I want to swap two columns in a data.frame. I know I could do something like:

```
dd <- dd[c(1:4, 6:5, 7:10)]
```

But I find it inelegant, potentially slow (?) and not program-friendly (you need to know `length(dd)`, and even have some cases if the swapped columns are close or not to that value...)
Is there an easy way to do it without reassigning the whole data frame?

```
dd[2:3] <- dd[3:2]
```

Turns out to be very "lossy" because the `[ <-` only concerns the values, and not the attributes. So for instance:

```
(dd <- data.frame( A = 1:4, Does = 'really', SO = 'rock' ) )
dd[3:2] 
dd[2:3] <- dd[2:1]
print(dd)
```

The column names are obviously not flipped...

Any idea? I could also add a small custom function to my very long list, but grrr... should be a way. ;-)

Comment: The `data.table` pacakge allows you to do reordering of columns w/out re-assignment, but the syntax probably doesn't get much cleaner than what you are doing- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232041/how-to-reorder-data-table-columns-without-copying

Comment: But it should be noted that `setcolorder` changes col order by reference. No copies are being made. So, it's *fast*.

Comment: It takes about 7 ms to reverse the columns in a 10 x 1e6 data frame. So unless you're doing this _all the time_, it's unlikely to be the bottleneck in your code, and you should worry about expressiveness, not speed.

Comment: @thelatemail Very good reference to "data.table", an incredibly awesome package. I almost mentioned it in my question, but wanted to keep it focused. So your comment is perfect, thanks ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a single function, but relatively simple:

```
dd[replace(seq(dd), 2:3, 3:2)]

  A   SO   Does
1 1 rock really
2 2 rock really
3 3 rock really
4 4 rock really
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
dd[,2:3] <- dd[,3:2]
```

works, but you have to update the names as well:

```
names(dd)[2:3] <- names(dd)[3:2]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I mentioned it in my question, it's not really what I am looking for. (I would like to avoid calling the names afterwards)