# How do I reorder data.table columns?

Tags: r, data.table

How do I permute columns in a `data.table`?
I can do that for a `data.frame`, but `data.table` overrides the method:

```
> df <- data.frame(a=1:3,b=4:6)
> df
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
> df[c("b","a")]
  b a
1 4 1
2 5 2
3 6 3
> dt <- as.data.table(df)
> dt
   a b
1: 1 4
2: 2 5
3: 3 6
> dt[c("b","a")]
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, c("b", "a")) : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), x must be keyed (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted) so data.table knows which columns to join to and take advantage of x being sorted. Call setkey(x,...) first, see ?setkey.
Calls: [ -> [.data.table
```

Note that this is *not* a dupe for [How does one reorder columns in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620885/how-does-one-reorder-columns-in-r).

Comment: The answers below provide the solution. [FAQ 2.1.7](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf) describes this difference between `data.table` and `data.frame`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `setcolorder`:

```
> library(data.table)
> dt <- data.table(a=1:3,b=4:6)
> setcolorder(dt, c("b", "a"))
> dt
   b a
1: 4 1
2: 5 2
3: 6 3
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how you do it in `data.table` (without modifying original table):

```
dt[, list(b, a)]
```

or

```
dt[, c("b", "a")]
```

or

```
dt[, c(2, 1)]
```

Comment: or `setcolorder(copy(dt), c('b','a'))`