# caught segfault error in R

Tags: r

I am getting a `caught segfault` error every time I try to run any plotting functions from the `ggplot2` package (1.0.0).  I have tried this with `qplot`, `geom_dotplot`, `geom_histogram`, etc. Data from the package (e.g. `diamonds` or `economics`) work just fine.

I am operating on Mac OS 10.9.4 (the latest version) and on R 3.1.1 (also the latest version).  I get the same error with the standard R GUI, RStudio, and when using R from the command line.  The command brings up the default graphic device (Quartz for R GUI and command line), but also the terminal error.

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(1:10)
```

gives me the error:

```
*** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: .Call("plyr_split_indices", PACKAGE = "plyr", group, n)
 2: split_indices(scale_id, n)
 3: scale_apply(layer_data, x_vars, scale_train, SCALE_X, panel$x_scales)
 4: train_position(panel, data, scale_x(), scale_y())
 5: ggplot_build(x)
 6: print.ggplot(list(data = list(), layers = list(<environment>),     scales = <S4 object of class "Scales">, mapping = list(x = 1:3),     theme = list(), coordinates = list(limits = list(x = NULL,         y = NULL)), facet = list(shrink = TRUE), plot_env = <environment>,     labels = list(x = "1:3", y = "count")))
 7: print(list(data = list(), layers = list(<environment>), scales = <S4 object of class "Scales">,     mapping = list(x = 1:3), theme = list(), coordinates = list(        limits = list(x = NULL, y = NULL)), facet = list(shrink = TRUE),     plot_env = <environment>, labels = list(x = "1:3", y = "count")))

Possible actions:

 1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
 2: normal R exit
 3: exit R without saving workspace
 4: exit R saving workspace
```

Here is my session info:

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  stats     methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_1.0.0 marelac_2.1.3 seacarb_3.0   shape_1.4.1   beepr_1.1     birk_1.1     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] audio_0.1-5      colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.4     grid_3.1.1       gtable_0.1.2    
[6] MASS_7.3-34      munsell_0.4.2    plyr_1.8.1       proto_0.3-10     Rcpp_0.11.2     
[11] reshape2_1.4     scales_0.2.4     stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.1.1
```

I've gathered from others that this is a memory issue of some sort, but this error occurs even when I have over 2 GB of free RAM.  I know this is a widely used package, so of course this doesn't happen for everyone, but why is it happening for me?  Does anyone know what I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: So if you start a brand new R session and run only those two commands (`library(ggplot2); qplot(1:10)`) you get that error? Can you add the output of `sessionInfo()` after running `library(ggplot2)`  to your question as well.

Comment: @MrFlick, yes, that is correct.  This error occurs during a brand new R session.  `sessionInfo` output is added.

Comment: Where/when are the "marelac_2.1.3, seacarb_3.0, shape_1.4.1, beepr_1.1     birk_1.1" packages being loaded? Do you have an `.Rprofile` set up somewhere? When you start R is it restoring a saved workspace (is there a `.Rdata` file in the working directory)?

Comment: @MrFlick, all those packages are being loaded from an `.Rprofile`, yes.  However, even if I remove the `.Rprofile`, the same problem occurs.  R is NOT restoring a saved workspace.

Comment: Can you kill -9 the process id and then try?

Comment: There are two different "latest versions" of R 3.1.1 for the Mac. http://cran.us.r-project.org/bin/macosx/  Do you have a mismatch of versions of any of your packages perhaps downloaded as binaries?... with the OS-distinct versions of R (note: the SL-version vs. the Mavericks-version)?_

Comment: @Mike.Gahan, I have been getting this same error for months so I do not think killing the process will help.

Comment: @BondedDust, I do not quite understand what you're asking.  I have the Mavericks version of R downloaded on my computer... is there a way you can reword your question?

Comment: So that's a start. Is it possible that you installed a ggplot2 binary that was developed for the SL version?

Comment: @BondedDust, nice idea but no.  I just double checked by installing the Mavericks version manually (rather than through RStudio) but I get the same result.

Comment: Time to construct a more complete bug report and send to the package maintainer.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In case anyone else has this problem or similar in the future, I sent a bug report to the package maintainer and he recommended uninstalling all installed packages and starting over.  I took his advice and it worked!

I followed advice from this posting: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Reset-R-s-library-to-base-packages-only-remove-all-installed-contributed-packages-td3596151.html

```
ip <- installed.packages()
pkgs.to.remove <- ip[!(ip[,"Priority"] %in% c("base", "recommended")), 1]
sapply(pkgs.to.remove, remove.packages)
```

Comment: You can then reinstall them again with `sapply(pkgs.to.remove, install.packages)`

Comment: I had a similar problem (with IRKernel / rzmq), but uninstalling an reinstalling packages did not help; see: https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/237.

Comment: @CephBirk what about packages that were not installed from CRAN :)? then `install.packages` doesn't retrive them

Comment: In my case, it did not work. My error was connected with `utils::download.file` and failed only in the `devtools::test()` runs and ONLY when done from rstudio. The solution I implemented was just using `system("wget ...")` instead of download.file.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer to this question but it might be helpful for someone. (Inspired by user1310503. Thanks!)

I am working on a data.frame df with three cols: col1, col2, col3.
Initially,

```
df =data.frame(col1=character(),col2=numeric(),col3=numeric(),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

In the process, rbind is used for many times, like:

```
aList<-list(col1="aaa", col2 = "123", col3 = "234")
dfNew <- as.data.frame(aList)
df <- rbind(df, dfNew)
```

At last, df is written to file via data.table::fwrite

```
data.table::fwrite(x = df, file = fileDF, append = FALSE, row.names = F, quote = F, showProgress = T)
```

df has 5973 rows and 3 cols. The "caught segfault" always occurs:

```
address 0x1, cause 'memory not mapped'.
```

The solution to this problem is:

```
aList<-list(col1=as.character("aaa"), col2 = as.numeric("123"), col3 = as.numeric("234"))
dfNew <- as.data.frame(aList)
dfNew$col1 <- as.characer(dfNew$col1)
dfNew$col2 <- as.numeric(dfNew$col2)
dfNew$col3 <- as.numeric(dfNew$col3)
df <- rbind(df, dfNew)
```

Then this problem is solved. Possible reason is that the classes of cols are different.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I hadn't ensured that my columns appeared in the same order before rbind(). Just reorder columns like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7496246/5021307 before rbind() to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to this question but it might be useful for someone. I had segfaults when I did `pdf` to create a PDF graphics device and then used `plot`. This happened with R 2.15.3, 3.2.4, and one or two other versions, running on Scientific Linux release 6.7. I tried many different things, but the only ways I could get it to work were (a) using `png` or `tiff` instead of `pdf`, or (b) saving large `.RData` files and then using a completely separate R program to create the graphics.

Comment: I have the same issue and that is the same workaround that I am using. Let me know if you were able to find a fix or a reason for this.

Comment: That's interesting. I only got segfaults when there was a very large object in memory (this object was not used in the `plot` command). Is it the same for you?

So another idea I had was to save the large object to disk and remove it from memory, either before doing `pdf` or between `pdf` and `plot`, and then reload it afterwards. But I haven't tried this yet as it would require some rewriting.

Comment: In my case I did not have any large objects. I explicitly ran a "gc()" to force garbage collection and checked the free memory just before running a "plot(1:10)" command. It had more than 20GB of free RAM at that point.