# R: data.entry - caught segfault

Tags: r, segmentation-fault, data-entry

Whenever I close the data.entry editor in R, R crashes with "caught segfault".

Just a simple example:

```
> x<-c(1,2)
> x
[1] 1 2
> data.entry(x)

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x7fff00010db0, cause 'memory not mapped'

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
```

I am working on Mac OSX 10.10.5 and R version 3.2.2. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [caught segfault error in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672974/caught-segfault-error-in-r)

Comment: @Narendra I'm not using any packages.

Comment: It might be a bug on Mac OSX .This code works fine on my system (R version 3.2.2 on 64-bit Ubuntu).