# Can't start R on server through VSCode

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I use vscode to ssh to my HPC server, on which I used miniconda to manage the environment.

I have used conda to install R. But once I start R, there's Segmentation fault (core dumped), with error message "address (nil), cause 'memory not mapped'".

However, when I ssh to HPC server using the terminal, I can start R without any problem.

What's the reason for the VScode not able to start R?

I ssh to HPC server using the terminal, I can start R without any problem.
I can also use webIDE to open the HPC server and start R session without any problem.

P.S when I install R version 3.5.0, it can work properly now.

Comment: I found the answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75897562/segfault-error-directly-after-r-startup-within-fresh-conda-env

Comment: By installing the language packs:
sudo apt-get install language-pack-en