# devtools::document() crashes with segfault when documenting R package

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools, roxygen2

I searched for this for a full day and I don't know how to find out why this happens and how to solve it.

When I run `devtools::document()` on a freshly started project (a package in a new directory) in RStudio, I get a

`*** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'`

And RStudio crashes.

Same when I try to do that from the command line.

Here is the full error:

```
==> devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace', 'vignette'))


 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
 2: library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib)
 3: loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]])
 4: namespaceImport(ns, loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),     versionCheck = vI[[i]]), from = package)
 5: loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]])
 6: namespaceImport(ns, loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),     versionCheck = vI[[i]]), from = package)
 7: loadNamespace(package, ...)
 8: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 9: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
10: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
11: tryCatch(loadNamespace(package, ...), error = function(e) e)
12: requireNamespace(dep_name, quietly = TRUE)
13: check_dep_version(pkg, version, compare)
14: check_suggested("roxygen2")
15: devtools::document(roclets = c("rd", "collate", "namespace",     "vignette"))
16: withCallingHandlers(expr, packageStartupMessage = function(c) invokeRestart("muffleMessage"))
17: suppressPackageStartupMessages({    oldLC <- Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_COLLATE")    Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_COLLATE", locale = "C")    on.exit(Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_COLLATE", locale = oldLC))    devtools::document(roclets = c("rd", "collate", "namespace",         "vignette"))})
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...

Exited with status 11.
```

And this is the result of `sessionInfo()`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] magrittr_1.5      data.table_1.11.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.2 tools_3.4.2    yaml_2.1.19
```

The same happens when I use the 'document' button in the IDE.

The package can be built, but I am using Roxygen for all the imports and exports.

I have NO idea how to troubleshoot this.

Some of the options were to use `devtools::clean_dll()` before document() and reinstall devtools, roxygen2, and Rcpp.

I tried all of those but nothing worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [caught segfault error in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672974/caught-segfault-error-in-r)

Comment: this is going to be hard because it's really tough to reproduce. Other than uninstalling/reinstalling I don't know what to suggest.

Comment: Besides uninstalling/reinstalling the packages you might also update to R 3.5.x.