# Dynamically sorting columns in dplyr via passing ordered vector with column names to select

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, dplyr

I'm using the code below to generate a simple summary table:

```
# Data
data("mtcars")
# Lib
require(dplyr)
# Summary
mt_sum <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(am) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(min, mean, median, max), mpg, cyl) %>%
  mutate(am = as.character(am)) %>%
  left_join(y = as.data.frame(table(mtcars$am),
                              stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
            by = c("am" = "Var1"))
```

The code produces the desired results:

```
> head(mt_sum)
Source: local data frame [2 x 10]

     am mpg_min cyl_min mpg_mean cyl_mean mpg_median cyl_median mpg_max cyl_max  Freq
  (chr)   (dbl)   (dbl)    (dbl)    (dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl)   (dbl)   (dbl) (int)
1     0    10.4       4 17.14737 6.947368       17.3          8    24.4       8    19
2     1    15.0       4 24.39231 5.076923       22.8          4    33.9       8    13
```

However, I'm not satisfied with the way the columns are ordered. In particular, I would like to:

1. Order columns by name
2. Achieve that via `select()` in `dplyr`

## Desired order

The desired order would look like that:

```
> names(mt_sum)[order(names(mt_sum))]
 [1] "am"         "cyl_max"    "cyl_mean"   "cyl_median" "cyl_min"    "Freq"       "mpg_max"   
 [8] "mpg_mean"   "mpg_median" "mpg_min"
```

### Attempts

Ideally, I would like to pass `names(mt_sum)[order(names(mt_sum))]` way of sorting the columns in `select()`. But the code:

```
mt_sum <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(am) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(min, mean, median, max), mpg, cyl) %>%
  mutate(am = as.character(am)) %>%
  left_join(y = as.data.frame(table(mtcars$am),
                              stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
            by = c("am" = "Var1")) %>%
  select(names(.)[order(names(.))])
```

Will return the expected error:

> ```
> Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
> The following do not:
> *  names(.)[order(names(.))]
> ```

In my real data I'm generating a vast number of summary columns. Hence my question, **how can I dynamically pass sorted column names to `select()` in `dplyr` so it will understand it and apply to the `data.frame` at Hand?**

---

*My focus is on figuring out a way of passing the dynamically generated column names to `select()`. I know that I could sort the columns in `base` or by typing names, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620885/how-does-one-reorder-columns-in-r).*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're definitely on the right path.

```
mt_sum <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(am) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(min, mean, median, max), mpg, cyl) %>%
  mutate(am = as.character(am)) %>%
  left_join(y = as.data.frame(table(mtcars$am),
                              stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
            by = c("am" = "Var1")) %>%
  .[, names(.)[order(names(.))]]
```

Comment: Amazing! So no `select()` in the whole thing and that's it!

Answer (score 11):

All you need is just:

```
mt_sum %>% select(order(names(.)))
#Source: local data frame [2 x 10]
#
#     am cyl_max cyl_mean cyl_median cyl_min  Freq mpg_max mpg_mean mpg_median mpg_min
#  (chr)   (dbl)    (dbl)      (dbl)   (dbl) (int)   (dbl)    (dbl)      (dbl)   (dbl)
#1     0       8 6.947368          8       4    19    24.4 17.14737       17.3    10.4
#2     1       8 5.076923          4       4    13    33.9 24.39231       22.8    15.0
```

It works, because `order` returns integer column positions, as required by `select`.

Comment: Thanks very much, neat solution and works really well.

Comment: If you're calculating summaries for grouped variables, you can remove these from the ordering and add them at the beginning. Like `select(group_var, order(names(.)[-1]))`