# list - create new column in data.frames with letters assigned to specific numbers

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have got a list with 10 data.frames, each one with 3 columns. I need to create a new column for each data.frame with letters. These letters have to be assigned conditionally on a specific data.frame column.

Here one of my data.frame within the list:

```
[[10]]
     x   y   z   
1   24  20  15    
2   25  15  25     
3   25  14  20
```

The column from which the new values have to be assigned is `z`. So lets say that 15 = S, 25 = A, 20 = T.

My data.frame with the new column should be:

```
[[10]]
     x   y   z  new_col
1   24  20  15   S  
2   25  15  25   A  
3   25  14  20   T
```

---

**UPDATE**

Here what I am trying with my real data (following @csgillespie suggestion):

```
lookup <- data.frame(num = c(-5, -1:8, 13:20, 25:32), let = c('P', 'A', 'E', 'AE', 'ASE', 'AS', 'ASW',
                                                                 'ZQ', 'AW', 'AN', 'OQ', 'AA', 'RT', 'SE', 
                                                                 'S', 'QP', 'W', 'NW', 'N', 'C', 'YE', 'PP',
                                                                 'ZQ', 'CS', 'L', 'CW', 'UW', 'CN'))

lst <- lapply(lst, function(i) 
    cbind(i, new_col=lookup[i$x, 2]))
```

But I got the following error, probably due to the negative numbers on the lookup data.frame:

> Error in `[.default`(xj, i) :    only 0's may be mixed with negative
>   subscripts

---

**2nd UPDATE**

Thanks @m-dz!

Job done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for a `merge()` for the readability:

```
dd <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3, z = 3:1)
dd_list <- list(dd, dd)
lookup <- data.frame(what = 1:3,
                     new_col = c("Q", "W", "E"))
lapply(dd_list, function(dd) merge(dd, lookup, by.x = "z", by.y = "what", sort = FALSE))
```

Edit: Forgot about the "list" part.

Edit 2: Just realised that `merge()` reorders the columns and sorts them by the `by` columns, `sort = FALSE` deals with the latter, but to keep the original order of columns they need to be reordered back. I would use `data.table` here with its `setorder()` (or its `merge()` implementation actually) or anything from here: [How does one reorder columns in a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620885/how-does-one-reorder-columns-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 0):

A simple `lapply` and `cbind` should work.

Example list

```
dd = data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3, z = 1:3)
l = list(dd, dd)
look_up = data.frame(value = 1:3, letter = c("A", "B", "Z"))
```

Then loop through each element of `l` and add a new column using `look_up` as a look up table

```
lapply(l,function(i) 
  cbind(i, new_col=look_up[i$z, 2]))
```

Comment: hi, thanks. the letters, for my real list, are not ordered alphabetically. Is there any way that I can first assign a specific letter to each number and then combine them into a new col?