# R combine two table in staggered(crossing) form

Tags: r

I want to combine two tables A and B in `R`

A has `col1 col2`

B has `colI colII`

with

```
cbind()
```

you will get

```
col1 col2 colI colII
```

I want result to be like this:

```
col1 colI col2 colII
```

which will be much helpful in comparing.

Comment: simply reorder them after applying `cbind()`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620885/how-does-one-reorder-columns-in-a-data-frame)

Comment: not so straight forward, want better and better solusion

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible using cbind function. You will have to create your own logic for same.

```
# create table 1 
t1 <- table(letters[1:2], sample(letters[1:2]))
# create table 2
t2 <- table(letters[3:4], sample(letters[3:4]))
df1 <- data.frame(cbind(t1,t2))
df1[,names(df1)][c("a", "c", "b", "d")]
# Output as below
#  a c b d
#a 1 1 0 0
#b 0 0 1 1
```

Comment: cbind and then df[,c(1,3,2,4)] is ok, but I hope there is more simple way:)

Comment: @cloudscomputes None that I am aware of :)

Answer (score 0):

For just two columns in each dataframe this approach seems the most straightforward:

```
# create 2 dataframes with 2 columns each:
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 2, 3), col2 = c(4, 5, 6))
df2 <- data.frame(coli = c(10, 20, 30), colii = c(40, 50, 60))
# bind them together in your order:
df3 <- data.frame(df1$col1, df2$coli, df1$col2, df2$colii)
```