# Error message when reorganizing duplicated columns in a dataframe with specifics names

Tags: r, dplyr

Ive been struggling to solve this.

This is my dataframe:

```
df<-structure(list(CESP6.MRVE3 = c(3.39731078, 3.351139056, 3.541515582, 
3.329084161, 3.117085569, 2.630336741, 3.263587913, 3.2854739, 
2.115273321, 1.255217018, 0.558756742, -0.478780166, -0.667471284, 
-0.814286812, -1.489226751, -1.957340764, -2.397829895, -2.106376737, 
-1.799451962, -0.699075436, -0.686257093, -0.397822857, -0.079821449, 
-0.532685698, -0.502453448, 0.124038498, -0.183209859, -0.207727845, 
-0.421813003, -1.550648396, -0.940915675, -0.282337163, -0.282104914, 
0.051723363, -0.095957822, -0.356446953, -0.586070428, -0.003895889, 
-0.706760138, -0.499624387, -0.265363282, 0.33515752, -0.056408244, 
-1.048118284, -1.251337786, -1.19362493, -1.519219549, -1.663016155, 
-1.036524208, -1.006369535, -1.066137285, -0.991731905, -1.463586221, 
-1.419036564, -1.121612261, -1.571668563, -1.494677088, -1.21322393, 
-0.758818549, -0.418730576, -0.080007787, 0.240368738, 0.050667688, 
-0.157657302, -0.327569328, -0.305106237, -0.070845132, 0.339675669, 
0.435446235, 0.323159091, 0.305477906, 0.500815644, 0.697451866, 
0.504088089, 0.185252695, 0.149946628, 0.098092312, -0.119733149, 
-0.03216457, -0.430422859, 0.056069088, 0.079253559, 0.651283822, 
0.302448429, 0.282680678, 0.137663163, 0.037606861, 0.175752544, 
0.619292269, 0.252188188, 0.629112963, 0.504017872, 0.236836216, 
-0.235883757, -0.3413341, -0.004198349, 0.018409018, 0.710295005, 
0.514988938, 0.4701157, 0.528261383, 0.569070737, -0.062206474, 
-0.597656818, -0.783107161, -0.670433093, -0.638114278, -0.705795463, 
-0.793188095, -0.502023489, -0.202656896, -0.335732122, -0.624201387, 
-0.282459676, -0.598342848, -0.705957332, -0.547667373, -0.703550544, 
-0.958645635, -0.74899049, -0.367393055, 0.188666063, 0.852927168, 
1.13423605, 1.400150892, 1.028440852, 0.96449997, 1.732501378, 
2.084243089, 1.743609682, 1.587293682, 1.309112969, 1.048557137, 
1.193750599, 1.337290323, 0.911695704, 0.793437415, 0.976832863, 
0.682248176, 0.479172951, 0.59335648, 0.825741995, 0.201656837, 
0.087715955, -0.200253782, -0.281464293, -0.423751438, -0.849923161, 
-0.548758555, -0.775574083, -0.812678164, -0.918994164, -0.712146965, 
-0.987741584, -0.999307348, -0.264546715, -0.110574162, 0.445984485, 
0.453985892, 0.342420128, 0.344738943, 0.105759274, 0.000519907, 
-0.4401135, -0.669592699, -0.851879843, -0.5891282, -0.32810787, 
-0.253702489, -0.260806569, -0.02863203, 0.183398233, 0.067082233, 
0.157891587, -0.261587611, -0.320423005, -0.704508163, -0.89442019, 
-0.835053597, -0.499715859, -0.48286866, -0.675799609, -0.894779279, 
-1.288575885, -1.754459056, -1.278111386, -1.262629372, -1.163618032, 
-0.725183796, -0.505528651, -0.866084482, -1.142400482, -0.924687626, 
-1.223090192, -0.949406191, -0.314712258, -0.191172534, 0.25963682, 
0.058215332, -0.397812115, -0.393406735, -0.201598324, -0.067770047, 
0.584115939, 0.347944216, 0.773070977, 0.653014674, 1.011737463, 
0.958085133, 0.961624857, 1.128838184, 1.255330131, 1.110456892, 
1.18112197, 1.675882603, 2.111364617, 1.567423735, 1.148732617, 
1.60076288, 1.300850854, 1.642159736, 0.943546194, 0.645076929, 
0.905164902, 1.041656849, 0.744552768, 1.02046761, 0.953718782, 
0.627979887, 0.420442978, 0.16096378, -0.26340993, -0.277350812, 
-0.239205128, -0.364511195, -0.034423222, -0.376277538, -0.197843302, 
0.077061607, -0.304504157, -0.2299545, -1.078212789, -0.954884041, 
-0.682276674, -0.435351899, -0.449226081, -0.174387872, -0.15653074, 
-1.569106437, -1.558230383), ABEV3.JBSS3 = c(-0.125505311, -0.381380131, 
-0.294037578, -0.298621426, -0.277723674, 0.387057047, 0.237627028, 
-0.176649161, -0.102841696, -0.204853657, -0.010728477, -0.088211983, 
0.291087137, -0.008015111, -0.500672558, -0.327838349, -0.381776712, 
-0.444424104, -1.109018008, -1.502966426, -1.311740904, -1.240197666, 
-1.028982199, -0.656137935, 1.150241417, 1.038229456, 1.044291093, 
0.66550656, 0.792223738, 1.085375662, 0.698835245, 0.35779654, 
0.052567206, 0.612173986, 0.083389453, 0.319778861, -0.009651158, 
-0.512944035, -0.334300455, -0.687285673, -0.249287579, -0.843563768, 
-0.350401788, -0.258858551, -0.224415656, -0.168036304, 0.283834704, 
0.714414741, 0.161747239, -0.066064038, -0.374848571, -0.193950819, 
-0.130798896, -0.071837601, -0.208030136, 0.039322473, -0.03913429, 
0.248536034, -0.052184956, -0.222250405, -0.172315854, 0.492137096, 
0.095606735, -0.194468769, -0.44615296, -0.284927438, -0.294029686, 
-0.388295819, -0.078033498, -0.263580547, -0.260100853, -0.300811787, 
0.256223106, 0.450348286, 0.327373124, 0.170197277, 0.040449544, 
0.541357351, 0.129345389, 0.848962225, 0.541458608, 0.374610532, 
0.276471485, 0.500596665, 0.462785388, 0.219492511, 0.589427062, 
0.190642529, 0.064439938, 0.586956432, 0.136880927, 0.06906965, 
-0.110678083, 0.292483896, 0.230154219, -0.0457206, -0.18159542, 
-0.597798011, -0.384963802, -0.235357022, -0.228649899, -0.143879233, 
-0.104917938, 0.0021069, -0.023450205, -0.023515654, -0.189718245, 
0.384734706, 0.199177601, 0.213302781, 0.097427962, -0.441038856, 
-0.135622705, -0.243433982, -0.495118173, -0.271310708, 0.030242585, 
0.139531651, 0.436238773, 0.493263611, 0.217706506, 0.29989523, 
0.237565553, 0.472981704, 0.566133628, 0.630258808, 0.63567496, 
0.614964025, 0.536179492, 0.643532101, 0.744112137, 0.422100176, 
-0.059911786, 0.03937728, 0.356412173, -0.134954303, 0.076588935, 
-0.64833274, -0.674525275, -0.693299752, -0.453365201, -0.547303564, 
-0.419950956, 0.089010339, 0.096362947, -0.129839643, -0.425386692, 
-0.175452141, -0.193908904, -0.04075698, -0.194705398, -0.169934733, 
-0.194200866, -0.047831569, 0.282748467, 0.23397399, 0.277135969, 
0.233187551, 0.242158901, 0.164019854, 0.303626634, 0.454852156, 
0.668987392, 0.807303201, 0.883682553, 1.13426259, 0.662896114, 
0.843813977, 0.119865559, -0.090855431, -0.138666708, -0.033896042, 
0.243456566, -0.103719281, -0.4641125, -0.323532464, -0.151026025, 
0.359881782, 0.246578849, 0.140386314, 0.550648636, 0.674446045, 
0.215661512, 0.294305092, -0.039315556, 0.12093671, -0.180429765, 
0.400150271, 0.187492824, -0.08289034, -0.053918989, -0.33560318, 
-0.30663183, -0.385088593, -0.155154042, -0.466520517, -0.092395337, 
-0.321507641, -0.363191832, -0.394220481, -0.877205699, -0.64888989, 
-0.393145968, -0.713231528, -1.132026116, -1.415646764, -0.897320899, 
-0.568359605, -0.672625738, -0.239146044, 0.204333651, -0.085741854, 
0.14225624, 0.26089982, -0.044657285, 0.363986295, 0.579402447, 
0.411908885, 0.466679551, 0.512413417, 0.83848511, 0.994556802, 
0.753835812, 0.724415849, 0.053694859, 0.08878324, 0.150008762, 
0.395107198, 0.110195579, 0.093347503, -1.15091863, -0.282910481, 
-0.267494329, -0.215633377, 0.022036947, -0.42029273, -0.194231093, 
-0.195269798, -0.321790104, -0.20927361, -0.2899946, -0.183287477, 
-0.255627209, -0.132475285, -0.411259818, -0.449716581, -0.291400772, 
-0.083074907, -0.093468127, 0.092911226), ABEV3.GOAU4 = c(-0.096399151, 
-0.430291395, -0.181638865, -0.199604415, -0.159431687, 0.126334543, 
0.089393571, 0.136005281, -0.03229346, 0.172789718, 0.262458491, 
-0.002791521, -0.021944077, -0.341429824, -0.525159639, -0.464133097, 
-0.517862913, -0.67650318, -1.187509124, -1.416482581, -1.415968328, 
-1.382063821, -1.091037279, -1.096116528, 0.720332754, 0.756782036, 
0.796100948, 0.446452774, 0.171031998, 0.690521674, 0.704946805, 
0.315973347, -0.031650677, 0.570725299, 0.068873875, 0.097688834, 
-0.240430809, -0.740941134, -0.567215724, -0.573140453, -0.243983969, 
-0.621932849, -0.263288653, -0.200571151, 0.036715276, 0.173668511, 
0.347069065, 0.654867781, 0.597926809, 0.429790496, 0.196410541, 
0.31726632, 0.459138342, 0.569311069, 0.279142271, 0.348981807, 
0.16238236, 0.575433053, 0.428321318, 0.104258311, -0.019633933, 
0.422912806, 0.266988077, 0.066998376, -0.116219151, -0.141298401, 
-0.19722313, -0.1914569, -0.236365387, -0.491794497, -0.421288579, 
-0.556880117, -0.229081401, -0.068908674, -0.212288629, -0.153465335, 
-0.244479614, -0.023461407, -0.245150402, 0.308404245, 0.475357481, 
0.380619757, 0.41113401, 0.592493743, 0.530633985, 0.305546401, 
0.523686642, 0.160648213, 0.09591049, 0.421847483, 0.072874025, 
0.106599435, 0.027276116, 0.232026103, 0.16728838, -0.080847933, 
-0.246268709, -0.57456745, -0.356768734, -0.237099961, -0.399463673, 
-0.2755675, 0.048149575, 0.304419759, 0.318665792, 0.226293745, 
0.119352773, 0.42783454, 0.279877325, 0.32614751, 0.271059925, 
-0.023507036, -0.013488402, -0.09907994, -0.29331371, -0.232295503, 
-0.111114867, -0.16721036, 0.081604599, 0.206354586, 0.100592285, 
0.286520943, 0.223986468, 0.446020918, 0.63331568, 0.568748719, 
0.534344186, 0.447394879, 0.567396844, 0.563333837, 0.57638453, 
0.429272794, 0.111144816, 0.089114295, 0.064547334, -0.286800135, 
-0.064424159, -0.383909906, -0.66322489, -0.7757677, -0.517977319, 
-0.71085332, -0.822704743, -0.207450802, -0.395237254, -0.352869613, 
-0.887948863, -0.750150147, -0.751164425, -0.497259918, -0.400306682, 
-0.512670394, -0.313522244, 0.239024494, 0.349880274, 0.379190851, 
0.461891683, 0.624779948, 0.335123438, 0.374621449, 0.570216916, 
0.579202638, 0.462424094, 0.78597874, 0.892257259, 0.960568264, 
0.65125328, 0.363279395, -0.041466663, -0.155862861, -0.201283637, 
-0.209411615, 0.040248824, 0.006015054, -0.183820553, -0.135176358, 
0.13330541, 0.37533986, 0.636691258, 0.385335454, 0.52855691, 
0.674160712, 0.478056884, 0.437213369, 0.120272397, 0.191469702, 
0.122658672, 0.639945099, 0.628256104, 0.16096527, -0.108691239, 
-0.141242384, -0.424118385, -0.467506675, -0.550203578, -0.750193279, 
-0.372565326, -0.353742033, -0.329162808, -0.623567341, -0.724240093, 
-0.257807481, -0.2342445, -0.1342342, -0.123378421, -0.385912896, 
-0.151162909, 0.094611656, 0.096987632, 0.557835076, 0.889877861, 
0.727343386, 0.861922611, 0.872095338, 0.610747869, 0.767709439, 
0.921272421, 0.966526362, 1.036186801, 1.18415628, 1.129751747, 
0.801794532, 0.745528276, 0.483164564, -0.102247876, -0.020375854, 
-0.249007786, -0.317981244, -0.465776031, -0.340009801, -1.570170265, 
-1.063900081, -1.037629896, -0.921009852, -0.63286961, -1.026932617, 
-0.820491669, -0.776928688, -0.946585198, -0.885233799, -0.704386355, 
-0.566254448, -0.368276634, -0.18623385, -0.294874117, -0.373172858, 
-0.119951402, -0.30977034, -0.171638433, 0.042436838), CESP6.PETR4 = c(2.698640815, 
2.652045837, 2.937365971, 2.693377102, 2.525824567, 2.41656399, 
2.862150684, 2.900076928, 1.863639826, 1.008959961, 0.514595849, 
-0.256362475, -0.403757133, -0.396946322, -0.584390173, -1.167579363, 
-1.610877236, -1.383908548, -1.022309956, 0.109713073, -0.055233353, 
0.190886461, 0.309187948, -0.156291597, -0.30059622, 0.286481151, 
0.296480384, 0.163715631, -0.082612787, -1.340165322, -0.513087952, 
0.20085019, 0.239042993, 0.382556698, 0.304313167, 0.1043124, 
0.028408418, 0.758674211, 0.05223711, -0.033558189, 0.366707604, 
0.694160217, 0.395916686, -0.577539063, -0.72881314, -0.754184002, 
-0.987906311, -1.25343505, -0.688963788, -0.811146228, -0.74705021, 
-0.734494061, -1.208907367, -1.25060588, -0.915127869, -1.405019953, 
-1.62368792, -1.329858462, -1.009641863, -0.634321728, -0.350541464, 
0.141639442, -0.545804409, -0.553248261, -0.633673464, -0.507395774, 
-0.27893641, 0.310638386, 0.208673313, 0.225799877, 0.295641233, 
0.113251723, 0.585166069, 0.603783309, 0.151709553, 0.028362486, 
0.032725064, -0.136476023, -0.315568427, -0.659823856, -0.117800827, 
0.221773969, 0.007795396, -0.302471931, -0.410873338, -0.39885031, 
-1.085810235, -1.054211642, -0.806443275, -1.079632465, -0.657076316, 
-0.557718886, -0.835380104, -1.277295984, -1.509685494, -1.144474042, 
-1.155481559, -0.669095185, -0.644999167, -0.439679033, -0.185158578, 
-0.231111753, -0.492336636, -0.797549622, -0.951696368, -0.476968843, 
-0.262181828, -0.301116356, -0.358826767, -0.386270618, 0.215001924, 
0.150164182, 0.118623546, 0.378731462, 0.158306258, -0.203076502, 
-0.003926142, -0.095999899, -0.682752753, -0.681154161, -0.402003801, 
0.228528551, 0.841775696, 1.033265605, 1.425179951, 1.053639314, 
0.964704787, 1.641515597, 1.956835732, 1.330349437, 1.193487899, 
1.195777487, 1.355085724, 1.504127401, 1.592053644, 1.398489212, 
1.356839892, 1.237747488, 1.19881296, 1.2674302, 1.194556764, 
1.195780113, 0.869500888, 0.80290591, 0.45232283, 0.187376404, 
-0.056079345, -0.631874644, -0.631233608, -0.944047554, -0.955055071, 
-0.992183169, -0.604474292, -0.697772165, -0.932501224, -0.428138645, 
-0.298988286, 0.360635704, 0.634623039, 0.544039959, 0.367129227, 
0.123298235, -0.054096423, -0.63590362, -0.921432358, -1.232015439, 
-0.869034853, -0.513398966, -0.428503268, -0.346213679, -0.196530199, 
0.07495971, 0.100171161, 0.352885186, 0.094375095, 0.056022881, 
-0.44168753, -0.591846174, -0.519931829, -0.223229701, -0.391739792, 
-0.527268531, -0.678759974, -0.923015403, -1.438119705, -1.252582204, 
-1.313698404, -0.771359622, -0.587737234, -0.445023209, -0.593691176, 
-0.827946605, -0.598371809, -0.935924344, -0.972835075, -0.444267029, 
-0.493892553, -0.156973059, -0.352768357, -0.797448223, -1.040262169, 
-0.991062616, -1.074676242, -0.601162537, -0.851321181, -0.469880465, 
-0.580039109, -0.362162059, -0.43987247, -0.419606677, 0.092574228, 
0.224863817, 0.37539617, 0.537419199, 0.865078882, 1.16970802, 
0.496785391, -0.043373253, 0.531413762, 0.343594667, 0.626733129, 
0.227532042, 0.32162806, 0.350196106, 0.460837142, 0.329987502, 
0.442543651, 0.346373109, 0.236372342, 0.015098265, -0.060805717, 
-0.328466934, 0.134454161, 0.246901626, 0.160148771, 0.629457008, 
0.497541128, 0.895891808, 1.232485252, 1.229078697, 1.190252852, 
0.495464304, 0.580735244, 0.968928048, 1.225314422, 0.944622658, 
1.717385877, 1.537335917, 0.04526216, -0.29505436), CESP6.MRVE3.new = c(2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), ABEV3.JBSS3.new = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ABEV3.GOAU4.new = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), CESP6.PETR4.new = c(2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-250L))
```

As you can seeI have columns named with begin names plus ".new"

I want do put them together, It is possible to do this with dplyr package. So the output will be:

```
CESP6.MRVE3|CESP6.MRVE3.new|ABEV3.JBSS3|ABEV3.JBSS3.new|ABEV3.GOAU4|ABEV3.GOAU4.new|CESP6.PETR4|CESP6.PETR4.new
```

This is what I am doing:

```
df %>%
  select(flatten_chr(map(colnames(df), ~c(.x , paste0(.x , ".new")))))
```

This is the wrong messge I am receveing:

```
Error: Unknown columns `CESP6.MRVE3.new.new`, `ABEV3.JBSS3.new.new`, `ABEV3.GOAU4.new.new` and `CESP6.PETR4.new.new` 
In addition: Warning message:
'glue::collapse' is deprecated.
Use 'glue_collapse' instead.
See help("Deprecated") and help("glue-deprecated").
```

What am I doing wrong??? Any help?

Comment: Are you saying you want to order your columns

Comment: @SmitM Yes. But my original dataframe is much bigger. I could do this mannually bt it will take to long. Thats why I posted my code.

Comment: Like so `df[order(names(df))]` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one reorder columns in a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620885/how-does-one-reorder-columns-in-a-data-frame)

Comment: `df[order(names(df))]`doesnt preserve the original alphabetic order of `df`.

Comment: Are the names always in this order: `c, a, b, c.new, a.new, b.new`?