# How do I remove na in R and make below value to go up

Tags: r, reshape

I have a data frame like below:

how do I remove na and use below value to go up?

Thanks

```
  id name.america name.europe name.asia
   1            a        <NA>      <NA>
   2         <NA>           b      <NA>
   3         <NA>        <NA>         c
   4            d        <NA>      <NA>
```

Change to:

```
  id name.america name.europe name.asia
   1            a           b         c 
   2            d
```

Comment: how did your data end up in this format? It feels odd to take a value for id=2, and move it to id=1. Id's should be your identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df1[, -1] <- lapply(df1[,-1], function(x) c(na.omit(x), rep("",length(x)-length(na.omit(x)))))
df1[1:max(colSums(!(df1[,-1]==""))),]

#  id name.america name.europe name.asia
#1  1            a           b         c
#2  2            d
```

Answer (score 3):

We can loop through the columns and remove the `NA`, then make the `lengths` of the `list` elements same by appending `NA` at the end after getting the `max` length of the `list` element.  Based on that, subset the 'id' column of the dataset and append with the output

```
lst <- lapply(df1[-1], na.omit)
lst1 <- lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst)))
out <- data.frame(lst1)
out1 <- cbind(id = df1$id[seq_len(nrow(out))], out)
out1
#  id name.america name.europe name.asia
#1  1            a           b         c
#2  2            d        <NA>      <NA>
```

If we need `NA` to be changed to blanks (`""`) - not recommended

```
out1[is.na(out1)] <- ""
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:4, name.america = c("a", NA, NA, "d"), 
name.europe = c(NA, "b", NA, NA), name.asia = c(NA, NA, "c", 
NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

[`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org)-based solution

```
require(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
    gather(key = "name", value = "val", -id) %>% 
    na.omit() %>% 
    select(-id) %>%
    group_by(name) %>% 
    mutate(id = 1:n()) %>% 
    spread(key = name, value = val)
```

## Results

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
     id name.america name.asia name.europe
  <int> <chr>        <chr>     <chr>      
1     1 a            c         b          
2     2 d            NA        NA
```

## Notes

- If desired you can re-order columns with [`select`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11311859/1655567) or that variable prior to transformation.
- `NAs` are left as such. If desired, you can use [`tidyr::replace_na`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/replace_na.html) to insert some string or space. I would discourage you from doing that.

---

## Data

*Taken from [@akrun's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53637147/1655567) above.*

```
df1 <- structure(
    list(
        id = 1:4,
        name.america = c("a", NA, NA, "d"),
        name.europe = c(NA, "b", NA, NA),
        name.asia = c(NA, NA, "c",
                      NA)
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA, -4L)
)
```