# changed column names after useing cbind

Tags: r, cbind

i have a Dataset-Matrix called Sigma_ma including Monthly Data from 30 european banks.
Now i have to check the connectedness between different pairs. Therefore my plan is to use cbind to create a new matrix, including the Data of some Banks. My Code:

```
Sigma_ma_bank_size <- cbind(Sigma_ma[,"HSBA.L"],Sigma_ma[,"BNPP.PA"],Sigma_ma[,"DBKGn.DE"],Sigma_ma[,"SAN.MC"],Sigma_ma[,"INGA.AS"],Sigma_ma[,"ISP.MI"]
                            ,Sigma_ma[,"UBSG.S"],Sigma_ma[,"RBS.L"],Sigma_ma[,"NDASE.ST"],Sigma_ma[,"KBC.BR"],Sigma_ma[,"DNB.OL"],Sigma_ma[,"SEBa.ST"]
                            ,Sigma_ma[,"ERST.VI"],Sigma_ma[,"PEO.WA"],Sigma_ma[,"BIRG.I"],Sigma_ma[,"DANSKE.CO"])
```

The Result is (shortened):

```
         V1         V2
 7.010374e-05 1.117888e-04
 4.271750e-05 1.207572e-04
```

how do I get the right name for the columns?
V1 -> HSBA.L
V2 -> BNPP.PA

thank you very much

Comment: colnames(Sigma_ma_bank_size) <- c('HSBA.L V2','BNPP.PA')

Comment: Duplicate of [How does one reorder columns in a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620885/how-does-one-reorder-columns-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 4):

All your columns come from the same source. Instead of using `cbind`, simply use `[` to subset instead with a vector of the columns you want:

```
Sigma_ma_bank_size <- Sigma_ma[,c("HSBA.L","BNPP.PA","DBKGn.DE","SAN.MC","INGA.AS","ISP.MI"
                            ,"UBSG.S","RBS.L","NDASE.ST","KBC.BR","DNB.OL","SEBa.ST"
                            ,"ERST.VI","PEO.WA","BIRG.I","DANSKE.CO")]
```

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
V1<-runif(2)
V2<-runif(2)



 Sigma_ma_bank_size<-matrix(V1,V2,nrow = 2,ncol = 2)

colnames(Sigma_ma_bank_size)<-c("V1","V2")
```

I' am assuming that after you do the `cbind` your data looks like the following

```
           V1        V2
[1,] 0.550721 0.1290283
[2,] 0.550721 0.1290283
```

you can then use the `colnames` to rename the columns based on the names of the Bank

```
colnames(Sigma_ma_bank_size)<-c('HSBA.L','BNPP.PA')

       HSBA.L   BNPP.PA
[1,] 0.550721 0.1290283
[2,] 0.550721 0.1290283
```