# Moving the last column to a nth place in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Good Day

I am trying to move the last column of a dataset to be the third column in a dataframe in R and was wondering what would be the most efficient way to do this.

My DataFrame structure is as follows:

```
 str(HR)
'data.frame':   2940 obs. of  36 variables:
 $ EmployeeNumber          : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Attrition               : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Age                     : int  41 49 37 33 27 32 59 30 38 36 ...
 $ BusinessTravel          : Factor w/ 3 levels "Non-Travel","Travel_Frequently",..: 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 3 2 3 
 $ DailyRate               : int  1102 279 1373 1392 591 1005 1324 1358 216 1299 ...
 $ Department              : Factor w/ 3 levels "Human Resources",..: 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ DistanceFromHome        : int  1 8 2 3 2 2 3 24 23 27 ...
 $ Education               : int  2 1 2 4 1 2 3 1 3 3 ...
 $ EducationField          : Factor w/ 6 levels "Human Resources",..: 2 2 5 2 4 2 4 2 2 4 ...
 $ EmployeeCount           : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ EnvironmentSatisfaction : int  2 3 4 4 1 4 3 4 4 3 ...
 $ Gender                  : Factor w/ 2 levels "Female","Male": 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ HourlyRate              : int  94 61 92 56 40 79 81 67 44 94 ...
 $ JobInvolvement          : int  3 2 2 3 3 3 4 3 2 3 ...
 $ JobLevel                : int  2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 2 ...
 $ JobRole                 : Factor w/ 9 levels "Healthcare Representative",..: 8 7 3 7 3 3 3 3 5 1 ...
 $ JobSatisfaction         : int  4 2 3 3 2 4 1 3 3 3 ...
 $ MaritalStatus           : Factor w/ 3 levels "Divorced","Married",..: 3 2 3 2 2 3 2 1 3 2 ...
 $ MonthlyIncome           : int  5993 5130 2090 2909 3468 3068 2670 2693 9526 5237 ...
 $ MonthlyRate             : int  19479 24907 2396 23159 16632 11864 9964 13335 8787 16577 ...
 $ NumCompaniesWorked      : int  8 1 6 1 9 0 4 1 0 6 ...
 $ Over18                  : Factor w/ 1 level "Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ OverTime                : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ PercentSalaryHike       : int  11 23 15 11 12 13 20 22 21 13 ...
 $ PerformanceRating       : int  3 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 3 ...
 $ RelationshipSatisfaction: int  1 4 2 3 4 3 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ StandardHours           : int  80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 ...
 $ StockOptionLevel        : int  0 1 0 0 1 0 3 1 0 2 ...
 $ TotalWorkingYears       : int  8 10 7 8 6 8 12 1 10 17 ...
 $ TrainingTimesLastYear   : int  0 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 2 3 ...
 $ WorkLifeBalance         : int  1 3 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 2 ...
 $ YearsAtCompany          : int  6 10 0 8 2 7 1 1 9 7 ...
 $ YearsInCurrentRole      : int  4 7 0 7 2 7 0 0 7 7 ...
 $ YearsSinceLastPromotion : int  0 1 0 3 2 3 0 0 1 7 ...
 $ YearsWithCurrManager    : int  5 7 0 0 2 6 0 0 8 7 ...
 $ AttritionB              : num  1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

and I am trying to have AttritionB come after Attrition.

`HRCorForm = HR[,c(1,2,36:35)]`, I have tried this code however it negates the rest of the columns

Kind Regards
Rehaan

Comment: try `HRCorForm = HR[,c(1,2,36,3:35)]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one reorder columns in a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620885/how-does-one-reorder-columns-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get all your columns:

```
HRCorForm = HR[,c(1,2,36,3:35)]
```