# How to create a new data frame with corresponding Row?

Tags: r

```
df <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
df1 <- c("Dog", "Apple", "Bat", "Cat")
mydata <- data.frame(df, df1)

mydata
  df   df1
1  A   Dog
2  B Apple
3  C   Bat
4  D   Cat
```

I have a long data set following this pattern. How can I arrange A = Apple, B = Bat............ creating a new column?

Further, is it possible for unequal row and column data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one reorder columns in a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620885/how-does-one-reorder-columns-in-a-data-frame)

Comment: Do you mean that you want to make a new column which is just the second column but sorted in alphabetical order?

Comment: I am trying to align with the rows which are not alphabetical. What if I have a long range of data c(A, B, C, D, .....) and another data set with c (Nepal, Bhutan, India, Bangladesh.... ), and I want D = Nepal, C = Bhutan, B = India and A = Bangladesh?

Answer (score 0):

you may try

```r
mydata$new <- sort(mydata$df1)

  df   df1   new
1  A   Dog Apple
2  B Apple   Bat
3  C   Bat   Cat
4  D   Cat   Dog
```