# Get the column number in R given the column name

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get column index from label in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427234/get-column-index-from-label-in-a-data-frame)

I need to get the column number of a column given its name.

Supose we have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(100),b=rnorm(100),c=rnorm(100))
```

I need a function that would work like the following:

```
getColumnNumber(df,"b")
```

And it would return

```
[1] 2
```

Is there a function like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 137, accepted):

```
which( colnames(df)=="b" )
```

Should do it.

Answer (score 74):

One fast and neat method is :

```
> match("b",names(df))
[1] 2
```

That avoids the vector scan that `==` and `which` do. If you have a lot of columns, and you do this a lot, then you might like the [fastmatch package](http://www.rforge.net/fastmatch).

```
> require(fastmatch)
> fmatch("b",names(df))
[1] 2
```

`fmatch` is faster than `match`, but on subsequent calls it's not just faster, it's instant.

Comment: If I'm using just one variable (one column), "match" and "which" both work equally as well for me.  However, if I'm using more than one variable, "which" throws errors, while "match" doesn't give me errors.  So for my situation, "match" is a superior choice.  Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

..especially, if you need to get several column indices the below approach applies:

```
> df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(100),b=rnorm(100),c=rnorm(100))
> which(names(df)%in%c("b", "c"))
[1] 2 3
```

if you use this for subsetting df you don't need which()

```
> df_sub <- df[, names(df)%in%c("b", "c")]
> head(df_sub)
           b          c
1  0.1712754  0.3119079
2 -1.3656995  0.7111664
3 -0.2176488  0.7714348
4 -0.6599826 -0.3528118
5  0.4510227 -1.6438053
6  0.2451216  2.5305453
```

Answer (score 14):

Another method which generalizes better to non-exact matching tasks is to use `grep` which returns a vector of numbers for matches with patterns within character vectors :

```
grep("^b$", colnames(df) )
```

If you wanted to remove by position number  all of the columns whose names begin with "b", you would write:

```
df[ , - grep("^b", colnames(df) )]
```

That neatly finesses  the issue that you cannot use negative indexing with character vectors.