# Get the column number in R given the column name for multiple variables

Tags: r, multiple-columns, label

I found partial answers in [Get the column number in R given the column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277363/get-the-column-number-in-r-given-the-column-name) and [Get column index from label in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427234/get-column-index-from-label-in-a-data-frame) but I couldn't find out how to do this for multiple variables. I tried putting all column names into a vector but that did not work.

Comment: Can you give a small example of what you're trying to do. What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Please give examples ideally in code

Answer (score 3):

You should really use **`match()`**.

> `match` returns a vector of the positions of (first) matches of its first argument in its second.

Syntax: `match( your_names_of_interest, names(your_df) )`

The other solution does not preserve order.  To illustrate why this is bad

```
df <- data.frame(foo=1:3, bar=4:6, qux=7:9)

multiple_names <- c('qux','bar','foo')

match(multiple_names,names(df)) # returns 3 2 1 (correct)

which(names(df) %in% multiple_names) # returns 1 2 3 (INCORRECT)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
View(colnames(dataframe))
```

This will output a table of the column numbers and column names

Comment: Can you add some context, perhaps showing how the output of this can be used?

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

```
which(names(train)%in% name of the variables in vector)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(1:length(all.names))[all.names %in% select.names]
```

Comment: More concisely this would be `which(all.names %in% select.names)`

Answer (score -2):

let x be the data frame and column.names be the set of names whose number you want to find. the following does the job.

```
which(names(x) == column.names)
```

Comment: Did you test this? That's not how `==` works.

Comment: `==` only works for single elements not multiple elements