# colMeans not working in R

Tags: r

The data set I have as file *Dummy.txt* is as follows

```
A|B|C|D
1|2|1.9|5
2.5|5|53|3
4|48|49|0.4
8|94|495|B6
```

(please note a text character in 5th row, 4th column)

I would like to obtain the mean of each column (i.e. column A, B, C and D).

The code I am using is as follows:

```
mydata_1 <- read.delim("Dummy.txt", skipNul = TRUE, sep = "|", header = FALSE, row.names = NULL)

mydata_1 <- as.numeric(as.character(mydata_1))

colMeans(mydata_1, na.rm = TRUE,)
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions please?

Comment: You have  column headers, so `header = TRUE` would be better. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Tried that, still doesn't help sorry.

Comment: and you have a non numeric entry in  column 4, row 4: B6

Comment: Output of `as.numeric(as.character(mydata_1))` is all `NA`s. You cannot directly convert a dataframe to numeric. Use `lapply/sapply` , convert the column into numeric and then take sum. `sapply(mydata_1, function(x) sum(as.numeric(x), na.rm = T))`

Comment: 5th row, 4th column - edited (sorry again)

Comment: @RonakShah: What is x here? 

Also, is there a comma after function(x)?

Comment: @Sharon `x` is used as an anonymous variable which represents the column and there is no comma after `function(x)` .

Comment: @RonakShah - thank you. Just one last question. In case there are no column headers, x would be a numeric (such as 2 corresponding to 2nd column)?
And for column average, I should use mean(as.numeric(x)...) ?

Comment: @Sharon yes, using `mean(as.numeric(x), na.rm = TRUE)` should work in that case.

Comment: [First convert the columns to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288485/how-to-convert-a-data-frame-column-to-numeric-type) and then [take sum of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006056/efficiently-sum-across-multiple-columns-in-r).

Comment: @RonakShah: For the fourth column, I am not getting the correct average here (due to the presence of a text character).

Comment: To turn the problem upside down: you might have used the parameter `colClasses` from `read.delim` to indicate that your columns should be integers. This would make the conversion unnecesary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `as.numeric(as.character(mydata_1))` returns `[1] NA NA NA NA`.

My suggestion would be to first go through all columns and coerce the types using `sapply()`, and then calculate the means of the columns:

```
library(magrittr)

mydata_1 %>% 
  sapply(., function(col) as.numeric(as.character(col))) %>% 
  colMeans(na.rm = TRUE)
```

This will return:

```
      A       B       C       D 
  3.875  37.250 149.725   2.800
```

Note: I am using `magrittr` to make use of the pipe (`%>%`) operator to chain the operations so you can check the output of every step.

Comment: hey, why not `sapply` and leave out the `do.call` part?

Answer (score 7):

You need to set `header = TRUE` to have the `A|B|C|D` row be used for column names, otherwise they are included as values, and all columns are parsed as string columns.

Then, passing `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` prevents columns D from being turned into a factor, and then the value 'B6' will automatically be turned into an NA when converted to a numeric type.

```r
mydata_1 <- read.delim("Dummy.txt", skipNul = TRUE, sep = "|", header = TRUE, 
                       row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

mydata_1[] <- lapply(mydata_1, as.numeric)
#> Warning message:
#> In lapply(mydata_1, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion

colMeans(mydata_1, na.rm = TRUE)
#>       A       B       C       D 
#>   3.875  37.250 149.725   2.800
```

The syntax `mydata_1[] <- ...` makes `mydata_1` keep its data frame structure even though a list is being returned on the right-hand side.

Comment: You've summarized all my thoughts exactly. This is definitely the correct approach IMO