# Weird error when summing across columns. This function doesn't seem to exist

Tags: r, sum, multiple-columns, tibble

Here is my data:

```
> factors.table
# A tibble: 10 x 7
   var          nfacts   corr corrAbs   l50   l70   l75
   <chr>        <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 mpg          127     0.837   0.837     1     1     1
 2 cylinders    5      -0.759   0.759     1     1     1
 3 displacement 81     -0.753   0.753     1     1     1
 4 horsepower   93     -0.667   0.667     1     0     0
 5 weight       346    -0.758   0.758     1     1     1
 6 acceleration 95      0.347   0.347     0     0     0
 7 year         13      0.430   0.430     0     0     0
 8 origin       3       0.514   0.514     1     0     0
 9 name         301     0.264   0.264     0     0     0
10 mpg01        2       1       1         1     1     1
```

I am trying to compute the sums of rows 5-7 as suggested here ([Efficiently sum across multiple columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006056/efficiently-sum-across-multiple-columns-in-r)) but I am getting this error:

```
> rowSums(factors.table[,5:7])
Error in weekSum(dat, start, end, c) :
argument "start" is missing, with no default
```

I have never seen `weekSum` before and it doesn't appear in R when I search `help(weekSum)`.

Comment: `rowSums` is from `base R`.  Can you try on a fresh R session without loading any other packages and do this again

Comment: It doesn't have any issue on tibble `iris1 <- as_tibble(iris);

> rowSums(iris1[1:4])#
  [1] 10.2  9.5  9.4  9.4 ...`

Comment: Can you show the `dput(head(factors.table, 6))`

Comment: Or try explicitly specifying base (if you have pother packages loaded) with `base::rowSums(factors.table[,5:7])`

Comment: for some reason my comment got deleted. but thank you @jpsmith this was very helpful!