# no visible global function definition for 'one_of'`

Tags: r, global-variables, dplyr, devtools

I am running an R CMD check using `devtools::check()` for a package I am writing and I encountered the following NOTE in the check:

`* checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE
prep: no visible global function definition for 'one_of'`

The only place in which I use `one_of` in `prep()` is with this line:

`raw_data <- dplyr::select(raw_data, -one_of(drop_vars))`

Does anyone knows how can I solve this `NOTE`?

Bellow is my `DESCRIPTION` and `NAMESPACE` files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is how my `DESCRIPTION` file looks like:

```
Package: prepdat
Title: xxx
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: person("Ayala S.", "Allon", email = "ayalaallon@gmail.com", role = c("aut", "cre"))
Description:xxx
Depends: R (>= 3.0.3)
License: GPL-3
LazyData: true
Imports: dplyr (>= 0.4.2),
    reshape2 (>= 1.4.1),
    psych(>= 1.5.4)
Suggests: knitr,
    testthat
```

And here is how my `NAMESPACE` file looks like

```
importFrom(dplyr,"%>%")
importFrom(psych,"harmonic.mean")
exportPattern("^[^\\.]")
```

Comment: Have you add the `@import dplyr` tag above your function? I think this is where the `one_of` function is defined. If you use the `@import` statement, there is no need for defining `dplyr::` in front of select.

Comment: @drmariod Thank you for your comment. Can you please clarify what you mean? The line of code in which I use `-one_of` is one line inside a bigger function. Should I add a line of `@import dplyr` before my big function? Thanks! Ayala

Comment: Perhaps try to also import package `lazyeval` and then use `select_(iris, interp(~-one_of(x), x = drop_vars))`

Answer (score 3):

`one_of` is not an exported function from `dplyr` so you can not use it in your package.

As stated in the [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) (which I advise you to read), it is better to program with `dplyr` using the underscored variants like `select_`.

Try this

```
raw_data <- dplyr::select_(raw_data, "-one_of(drop_vars)")
```

Also, I would avoid using the pipe operator within a package code. It is aimed at interactive use rather than for use within a function.

Comment: Thank you. I decided not to use `dplyr::one_of` in my code. This is what I did: `drop_vars` is still a string vector argument (e.g., `drop_vars = c("prime_type", "font_size")` with the name of the columns you want to drop. Inside the function: `index_col <- c() # Reset i to 1 i <- 1 while (i <= length(drop_vars)) { index_col[i] <- which(colnames(raw_data) == drop_vars[i]) i <- i + 1} keep_col <- -index_col raw_data <- raw_data[, keep_col]`. It works great. The idea to use which I got from answer #2 in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427234/get-column-index-from-label-in-a-data-frame