# Renaming values based on location in dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am trying to rename values within a dataframe in R based on their location within the dataframe itself. Here is the dataframe that I am currently working with:-

```
df<-structure(list(UserID = c("hdyyu-192", "yeui-1893", "dnnd-1882", "nopr-738", "ieka-1728"), 
                   `05/06/2021` = c("Activity B", "Activity A", "Activity B", "Activity C", "Activity D"), 
                   `06/06/2021` = c("Activity B", "Activity A", "Activity A", "Activity C", "Activity D"), 
                   `07/06/2021` = c("Activity D","Activity A", NA, "Activity C", "Activity D"), 
                   `08/06/2021` = c("Activity A","Activity B", NA, "Activity B", "Activity A"), 
                   `09/06/2021` = c("Activity A","Activity B", NA, "Activity B", "Activity C"), 
                   `10/06/2021` = c("Activity C",NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                   `11/06/2021` = c("Activity B", NA, NA, NA, NA)), 
              class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,-5L))

head(df)

# A tibble: 5 x 8
#  UserID    `05/06/2021` `06/06/2021` `07/06/2021` `08/06/2021` `09/06/2021` `10/06/2021` `11/06/2021`
#  <chr>     <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>       
#1 hdyyu-192 Activity B   Activity B   Activity D   Activity A   Activity A   Activity C   Activity B  
#2 yeui-1893 Activity A   Activity A   Activity A   Activity B   Activity B   NA           NA          
#3 dnnd-1882 Activity B   Activity A   NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          
#4 nopr-738  Activity C   Activity C   Activity C   Activity B   Activity B   NA           NA          
#5 ieka-1728 Activity D   Activity D   Activity D   Activity A   Activity C   NA           NA
```

And here is the result that I would like to achieve:-

```
# A tibble: 5 x 8
#  UserID    `05/06/2021`       `06/06/2021`       `07/06/2021`       `08/06/2021`       `09/06/2021`       `10/06/2021`       `11/06/2021`      
#  <chr>     <chr>              <chr>              <chr>              <chr>              <chr>              <chr>              <chr>             
#1 hdyyu-192 Activity B event_1 Activity B event_2 Activity D event_3 Activity A event_4 Activity A event_5 Activity C event_6 Activity B event_7
#2 yeui-1893 Activity A event_1 Activity A event_2 Activity A event_3 Activity B event_4 Activity B event_5 NA                 NA                
#3 dnnd-1882 Activity B event_1 Activity A event_2 NA                 NA                 NA                 NA                 NA                
#4 nopr-738  Activity C event_1 Activity C event_2 Activity C event_3 Activity B event_4 Activity B event_5 NA                 NA                
#5 ieka-1728 Activity D event_1 Activity D event_2 Activity D event_3 Activity A event_4 Activity C event_5 NA                 NA
```

As you can see within the desired outcome, the term "event_" followed by the column number (skipping the first column) is pasted after the value in each corresponding cell. Is there a solution that would allow me to achieve this with my original dataframe? Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part that match the event number to the index of column is borrowed from this question: [Get column index from label in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427234/get-column-index-from-label-in-a-data-frame).

I will be using a `dplyr` approach.

Use `mutate()` in everything column except the `UserID`. If the value in the column is `NA`, do nothing. If it's not `NA`, `paste()` the value in the column with "event_indexOfColumn", which is returned by using `grep()` and `cur_column()`.

Note we have to subtract the "column index" by 1, since column 1 is not used to generate the column index.

```
df %>% mutate(across(-UserID, ~ ifelse(
  is.na(.x),
  .x, paste0(.x, " event_", as.numeric(grep(
    cur_column(), colnames(df)
  ) - 1))
),
.names = "{.col}"))
```

### Output

You will see `NA` in the results as in your desired output (I'm using `clipr::write_clip()` to copy the output here, which removes the `NA`).

Or anyone could recommend how to include output with lots of columns?

```
UserID  05/06/2021  06/06/2021  07/06/2021  08/06/2021  09/06/2021  10/06/2021  11/06/2021
hdyyu-192   Activity B event_1  Activity B event_2  Activity D event_3  Activity A event_4  Activity A event_5  Activity C event_6  Activity B event_7
yeui-1893   Activity A event_1  Activity A event_2  Activity A event_3  Activity B event_4  Activity B event_5      
dnnd-1882   Activity B event_1  Activity A event_2                  
nopr-738    Activity C event_1  Activity C event_2  Activity C event_3  Activity B event_4  Activity B event_5      
ieka-1728   Activity D event_1  Activity D event_2  Activity D event_3  Activity A event_4  Activity C event_5
```

### `dput()` result FYI

```
structure(list(UserID = c("hdyyu-192", "yeui-1893", "dnnd-1882", 
"nopr-738", "ieka-1728"), `05/06/2021` = c("Activity B event_1", 
"Activity A event_1", "Activity B event_1", "Activity C event_1", 
"Activity D event_1"), `06/06/2021` = c("Activity B event_2", 
"Activity A event_2", "Activity A event_2", "Activity C event_2", 
"Activity D event_2"), `07/06/2021` = c("Activity D event_3", 
"Activity A event_3", NA, "Activity C event_3", "Activity D event_3"
), `08/06/2021` = c("Activity A event_4", "Activity B event_4", 
NA, "Activity B event_4", "Activity A event_4"), `09/06/2021` = c("Activity A event_5", 
"Activity B event_5", NA, "Activity B event_5", "Activity C event_5"
), `10/06/2021` = c("Activity C event_6", NA, NA, NA, NA), `11/06/2021` = c("Activity B event_7", 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```